# Combining 2 queries into 1 struct

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have 2 different databases and I need to get results of their queries into 1 structure:

```
struct my_order
{
    public int Id_N
    public int OrderId;
    public string Discount;
    public string CustomerId;
    public string ShipAddress;
}
```

My queries:

```
my_order ret = new my_order();     
SqlConnection con = open_sql(firstDB);

string firstQuery= @" SELECT OrderId, Discount FROM Orders 
                      WHERE Id = " + id_n.ToString(); //some ID that I got earlier

SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(firstQuery, con);
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    ret.Id_N = id_n;
    ret.OrderId = reader["OrderId"].ToString();
    ret.Discount = reader["Discount"].ToString();
}

SqlConnection second_con = open_sql(secondDB);

string secondQuery= @" SELECT CustomerId, ShipAdress FROM Details
                       WHERE Id = " + id_n.ToString(); 
//id_n - some ID that I got earlier(the same as in the first query)

SqlCommand secondCommand = new SqlCommand(secondQuery, second_con);
SqlDataReader secondReader = secondCommand.ExecuteReader();

while (secondReader.Read())
{
    ret.Id_N = id_n;
    ret.CustomerId = secondReader["CustomerId"].ToString();
    ret.ShipAddress = secondReader["ShipAddress"].ToString();
}
```

The problem is that compiler get the result from the `firstQuery` and doesn't from the `secondQuery`. It doesn't get into `while(secondReader.Read())`.

How to correct it?

PS: I change the code and queries a little bit, because my is too big, but the question is the same.

Regards,
Alexander.

Comment: Maybe there is no data returned from the second query? Note that by calling ToString on an int you're formatting using the current locale. That could introduce different formatting than the database expects. Try using parameters instead. Also make sure you dispose the DataReaders when you're done reading data.

Comment: create stored proc and do union all and simply exec stored proc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it doesn't go into the `while (secondReader.Read()) { ... }` is because the second query does not return any rows, because there are no rows in table Details with the specified Id value.

Comment: I'll check again, but I think secondQuery return data

Answer (score 1):

Shooting into the blue here without an error or a more detailed description of what is going wrong, but you have a typo in your code:

```
string secondQuery= @" SELECT CustomerId, ShipAdress FROM Details WHERE Id = " + id_n.ToString(); 
ret.ShipAddress= secondReader["ShipAddress"].ToString();
```

You are writing ShipAdress with one and 2 d's.

Choose the correct version

Answer (score 0):

you may use the propriete HasRows and  IsDBNull(columnIndex) method to check if it contains data

```
if (secondReader.HasRows)
   // Get  data
else
  //there is no data
```